# What is the preferred link format in questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I recently answered a question and in my answer I linked to an external site. I left the link as is because I think it's fairly descriptive, for example:

> http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

I could have formatted the link as:

> [WGET for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

Or, I could have formatted it as:

> [WGET for Windows (SourceForge)](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

The third format provides a hint as to the link destination without moving the mouse over the link.

What's the preferred link format for the Stack Overflow trilogy of sites?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer either the second or third options.

Comment: I agree. It makes the link look better, I find the first to look unprofessional, and gives the impression the OP didn't try very hard.

Comment: +1: They are especially good because they are usually shorter, and thus create less clutter.

Answer (score 2):

Fully agree with [Bill the lizard's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22582/189029), but it needs an addition:

Add additional text behind the link describing what it points to, especially when changing the bare URL to text disguises information:

In the question example:

[WGET for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) *(sourceforge)*.

Or when the link does not go to a HTML page (which people usually expect): *(pdf)*.
Or, on a site like [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) where references are important: *(NY Times, 29 November 2018)*

In addition to readability, we should also strive for maximum information.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone for /. style?

> [Wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) [sourceforge.net]

Comment: I think the reason that Slashdot went with that was to prevent people from linking to bad, disgusting things in disguise. I don't see that being a problem here on Stack Overflow, especially with the fast response of users and moderators to problem postings.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you; the question's 3rd suggested format reminded me of it though. Just thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: @Thomas Owens, @Alex Barret: but given that this would not be enforced by SO, but rather by the poster, you could do something like `<a href='goiatze.cx'>My little Pony</a>[nicepony.com]`, thus defeating the reason. Add tinyurl.com and you have Gtzcx hell. I always hover links and look at the status bar anyway :P

Comment: @free voyager: The link would then show as `My litte Pony [goiatze.cx] [nicepony.com]`

Answer (score 1):

I usually give a name to the link. That way it is easier to maintain the post.

[**Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518359/how-do-i-get-perl-pod-in-string-and-print-it-in-page):

> I have a POD document. Now, I want to
>   convert that POD to a parsed section
>   like usage/description and get it in a
>   string.
>
> Why not [`pod2usage`][pod2usage]?
>
> This doesn't help me to get the output
>   in string but in STDOUT/file. I am
>   stressing on the point "getting it in
>   string", because I want to display the
>   POD in "pages" if the length exceeds
>   screen length.
>   [`pod2usage`][pod2usage] doesn't print
>   them in pages :(
>
> Can somebody tell me which module to
>   use for this purpose?
>
> [pod2usage]:
>   http://perldoc.perl.org/pod2usage.html