# What's the preferred format when linking posts within the same network?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, rollbacks

For links internal to the network where I am posting, I usually just paste the URL as it will be automatically replaced with the title of the linked post. However, I recently had [one such instance edited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/276951/revisions), which makes me hesitant about the preferred way to format links.

I originally started my question with

> In Gnome 3.18, it was possible to change the titlebar height of all windows by changing the css in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css as per [Reduce title bar height in gnome 3 / gtk+ 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257163/reduce-title-bar-height-in-gnome-3-gtk-3).

Another user edited this to

> In Gnome 3.18, it was possible to change the titlebar height of all windows by changing the css in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css as per [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257163/reduce-title-bar-height-in-gnome-3-gtk-3).

I prefer my initial formatting as it is more descriptive, which is similar to the preferred reasons stated in [What is the preferred link format in questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22581/what-is-the-preferred-link-format-in-questions-and-answers). As that question deals with external links, I just wanted to ask here which is the preferred way to format network internal links and if I can confidently rollback the edit to my post or should consider changing my formatting of future links.

Comment: Typical case of robo reviewers. That edit should have been rejected, and you have full right to roll it back now, optionally explaining to the editor via comment reply that such edits are wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, that edit should have been rejected. What a useless edit.

That said, back to your question... I would always use a title that is as descriptive as possible, hence using the magic link is the best option. It makes clear where you are going.

Take your question as an example. What is clearer in your opinion? This:

> which is similar to the preferred reasons stated in [What is the preferred link format in questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22581/what-is-the-preferred-link-format-in-questions-and-answers)

Or:

> which is similar to the preferred reasons stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22581/what-is-the-preferred-link-format-in-questions-and-answers).

Where is *here*? The first link is clear, the second isn't.